# When extracting URLs from browser history it shows Cannot resolve symbol 'BookmarkColumns'

Tags: java, android, uri, android-permissions, android-query

I'm trying to extract URLs from browser history. I've found below code and try to implement it. But the problem is it gives error in `BookmarkColumns`, `BOOKMARKS_URI`, `noicon`.

I tryed this in API levels 16,23,25. But the error dosent solve. It always says that **"Cannot resolve symbol 'BookmarkColumns' "**

Please help  me to resolve this...

```
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.Browser;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ArrayList<String> titles;
    private ArrayList<String> urls;
    private ArrayList<Bitmap> bitmaps;
    private ContentResolver cr;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        createLists();
    }

    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        getBH();
        showHistoryBookmarks();

    }

    public void createLists() {
        titles = new ArrayList<String>();
        urls = new ArrayList<String>();
        bitmaps = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();

    }

    public void getBH() {
        Bitmap icon;
        cr = getContentResolver();
        String order = Browser.BookmarkColumns.DATE + " DESC";
        String[] projection = {Browser.BookmarkColumns.TITLE, Browser.BookmarkColumns.URL, Browser.BookmarkColumns.FAVICON};
        //String selection=projection[0]+"=?";
        //String args[]={"Google"};
        Cursor rows = cr.query(Browser.BOOKMARKS_URI, projection, null, null, order);
        if (rows.getCount() > 0) {
            while (rows.moveToNext()) {
                //read title
                String title = rows.getString(rows.getColumnIndex(projection[0]));
                //read url
                String url = rows.getString(rows.getColumnIndex(projection[1]));
                //read icon
                byte[] bicon = rows.getBlob(rows.getColumnIndex(projection[2]));
                if (bicon != null) {
                    //convert blob image data to Bitmap
                    icon = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bicon, 0, bicon.length);

                } else {
                    //default icon for history and bookmarks that do not icons
                    icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.noicon);
                }
                //add to lists
                addToList(title, url, icon);
            }
            //close the cursor
            rows.close();
        }


    }


    public void addToList(String title, String url, Bitmap bitmap) {

        titles.add(title);
        urls.add(url);
        bitmaps.add(bitmap);

    }


    public void showHistoryBookmarks() {
        ListView l = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.hb_list);
        if (l != null) {
            if (titles.size() > 0) {
                ListAdapterModel aa = new ListAdapterModel(this, R.layout.listlayout, R.id.hbtitle, titles, urls, bitmaps);
                l.setAdapter(aa);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "This is no bookmark or history.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Those APIs were removed in the Android 7.0 SDK, IIRC. They were never a particularly good idea in the first place.

Comment: Thank you. If they remove those APIs, then they must add similar APIs I think. Isn't there any APIs @CommonsWare ? . Sorry if I bother you. I'm so stressed.

Comment: "If they remove those APIs, then they must add similar APIs I think" -- no. Each browser app, if it chooses, can have its own APIs for this.

Comment: If I want to chrome browser history, Is there any APIs to do it ? any suggestions ?

Comment: I do not know if Chrome has an API for this -- sorry!

Comment: Thank you very much for you valuable time...

Answer (score 2):

try these [chrome history API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/history). Read documents and give a try. I didn't try it. But thought would be insperation.